# if record of table is null then email should not be sent

Tags: php, oracle

I am working on a PHP project and I need to send data of tables to some recipients only if there is record in the table else email should not be sent.

please correct my 'if' condition as I am new in php.

```
 // if record is null then email should not be sent.
     $sql="SELECT * FROM tmp_Roshan_line T ";
     $result = odbc_exec($connect_cc, $sql) or die("Couldn't execute query! ".odbc_errormsg());

      if ($result!=NULL){

//Sending Email
$htmlbody ="
<head>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 0px;
    width: 20%;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size:12px;
    border: 0px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

th {
    background-color: #68a936;
    color: Black;
    border: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>";
$htmlbody .= "<p style='font-size:14;'>Dear Roshan Team,<br><br>
Following lines are dedected as 100% simbox lines by our detection tool, please block them and confirm with us. <b>"."</b></p><br><br>";



$htmlbody .= "
```

Comment: use if($result), that should work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Retrieving Records**
The **odbc_fetch_row()** function is used to return records from the result-set. This function returns true if it is able to return rows, otherwise false.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM tmp_Roshan_line T";
$rs=odbc_exec($connect_cc,$sql);
if (!$rs)
  {
  exit("Error in SQL");
  }


while (odbc_fetch_row($rs))
{

 //Sending Email
$htmlbody ="
<head>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 0px;
    width: 20%;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size:12px;
    border: 0px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

th {
    background-color: #68a936;
    color: Black;
    border: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>";
$htmlbody .= "<p style='font-size:14;'>Dear Roshan Team,<br><br>
Following lines are dedected as 100% simbox lines by our detection tool, please block them and confirm with us. <b>"."</b></p><br><br>";


// send email code 
}
odbc_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check the condition without comparing it to NULL.

```
if ($result){
   # condition goes here
 }
```

or if you really want to check it against null value you can do so
by using php [`is_null`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) function

```
if (!is_null($result)) {
   # condition goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if (odbc_num_rows($result)>0){
 //send mail
  }
else{
      //dont send mail
    }
```

orbc_exec() here will return false only if there is an error in running the query. This shall return true even if there are no results in your query execution. The best way is to count the number of rows returned. For that you need to use `[odbc_num_rows()][1]`